# create a new div with some element in asp.net, with server side accessibility

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, webforms, createelement

I need to create one div element like this with some server side textbox. but as i searched it's not possible to make asp.net elements by html codes.

```
<div>
      <p>
      Title
      </p>
      <p>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="chBox" runat="server" />
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      </p>
</div>
```

So i tried jQuery functions to add some elements by  $("div").append($something); but i couldn't get the value of html text inputs in server side! (i use asp.net webforms)
So how can i create some html text inputs and get their value in server side at submits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create a html input field with the name attribute included in it.

```
<input id="txtBox" name="MyData" ... />
```

Then from the server side you can access the textbox value like this.

```
string sub = Request["MyData"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an `html input` and set its attribute `name` then you can get its value using `name` attribute in server side code.

```
<input type="text" name="someText" />
```

C#

```
string val = Request.Form["someText"].ToString();
```

Comment: @HudhaifaYoosuf what you mean ?